# Создать функцию Калькулятор JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**Ребята**, помогите выполнить это задание, это всё что у меня есть, у меня мозг взрывается, кучу всего перечитал и не решаюсь начать туда что нибудь писать. Какой же язык сложный для меня :(

== Название count. Функция принимает 3 параметра:

первый параметр типа Number,
второй параметр типа Number,
третий параметр типа String,

в который передается значение операции. Значениями операции могут быть: «+», «-», «*» и «/». Функция должна вернуть результат выполненной операции с помощью return.
 * Совет: используйте конструкцию switch. ==

```
function count (num1, num2, mark) {
}
```

Comment: откуда задание?

Comment: а какой язык для вас не сложный?

Comment: @Bookin русский

Comment: @totorro к чему это? Я интересуюсь потому как, судя по выражению, человек знаком с каким либо языком программирования, и во многих есть аналогичные конструкции (логические операторы)

Comment: @Bookin я незнаком с каким либо языком программирования. Знакомлюсь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

сам новичок, мой вариант

```
function count(num1, num2, method) {
      switch (method) {
        case "+":
          return num1 + num2;
          break;
        case "-":
          return num1 - num2;
          break;
      } 
    }
```

Comment: После return break уже не нужен.

Comment: супер! дал толчок, дописал умножение и деление, ответ засчитан! спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
function count(num1, num2, mark) {
  switch (mark) {
    case "*":
      return num1 * num2;
    case "+":
      return num1 + num2;
    case "-":
      return num1 - num2;
    case "/":
      if (num2 !== 0) {
        return num1 / num2;
      } else {
        return "не делится на нуль";
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function count(a, b, o) { return eval(a + o + b) };
```

далее пример

```js
$('body').append(count(4, 3, '+'));
$('body').append(count(4, 3, '-'));
$('body').append(count(4, 3, '/'));
$('body').append(count(4, 3, '*'));

function count(a, b, o) { return wrap(eval(a + o + b)) }
function wrap(v) { return '<p>' + v + '</p>' }
```

```html
<body><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script></body>
```

Comment: _* Совет: используйте конструкцию switch._

Comment: @Grundy всегда полезно знать "а как еще"...

Comment: Кажется в вопросе не было jquery.

Comment: @VasilyukDmitry, jquery не является частью ответа. Он нужен просто для демонстрации вывода. Весь ответ заключается в самой первой строчке

Comment: Стоит предупредить, что такой способ нежелателен, т.к. небезопасен: `eval()` позволяет выполнить любой код.

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать свою небольшую математическую библиотеку:

```js
var myMath = {
  "+" : function(a,b){ return a+b },
  "-" : function(a,b){ return a-b },
  "*" : function(a,b){ return a*b },
  "/" : function(a,b){ return a/b },
  "calc": function(a, b, op){ return this[op](a,b) }
}

document.getElementById("out").innerText = myMath.calc(5, 6, "+");
```

```html
<div id="out"></div>
```